# Is there a way to create a relationship between a column and an entire table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I want to make two tables (say) `contact` and `contact_info`.

```
CREATE TABLE contact (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)
CREATE TABLE contact_info (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email TEXT, address TEXT)
```

**Requirement**: when contact is inserted in `contact` table then `contact_info` table is created automatically and it is related to that contact (where 'contact' in `contact_info` is replaced with `contact`'s name), so that when the contact is deleted the whole related table is deleted.

Is there a statement in `SQLite` to do it?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Do you want to create new tables on the fly for each contact? If so, this is ill-advised database design. Use foreign key, *contact_id*, in *info* table. Then set up [triggers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) for cascading row deletes.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? Usually, databases are not designed to work with millions of tables, but they are designed to work with millions of records. If you need several info records to be associated with one contact, you use a one-to-many relation between two tables.

Comment: For creating a tables it's not complicated I can do it with coding, what I'm trying to reach is: Can I make a relationship between a row and a whole table, so when I delete the row the table is droped?

Comment: Why a new table for each contact? You can use one table for all contacts if you add the conctact's ID as a foreign key in the `info` table. With `ON DELETE CASCADE` all rows for a contact get deleted in `info`, when the contact gets delete. Or even simpler, as it looks like this is one on one relation, just add the `email` and `address` columns to `contact`.

Comment: Again, why? I think you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), in which you are thinking of an implementation which is not necessarily the correct one for solving your real problem. What kind of requirement are you trying to solve by creating and dropping tables?

Comment: Okey, I'm not an expert anyway, maybe my example is a bad one or maybe it's the way am thinking or my knowledge. I'll give another example maybe your explanations well make it clear for me since this is the nearest example: if we say There is a school: it has multiple teachers, and multiple courses. After I create a study class or group for a specific course assigned to a teacher from the school, I want to add students aren't recorded in the school from the beginning, doesn't that require a new table for class students? so when I delete this class students will be no more needed in recoreds?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can use your usual students table, but keep a column that says that this student is registered. When you delete the class, you will first delete all the students that are connected to this class, and have "false" in the "registered" column. Then you'll delete the class record.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question if you can create a relation between a column and an entire table is no, what you're trying to do is not how databases work, but what you can do is set the `contact id` as a foreign key for the `contact_info` table, or you can even make them as a single table and the default value for the `contact_info` attributes to NULL.